# make a delay in a method call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have search-bar (Text Field) component and according to what user types there it updates a list. The issue is that for each character that the user enters the list updates, so if they want to write `Learn React` the list changes 11 times!
I need to do something that delays the function (updateList) calls, let's say make it called every 1 second even if it's called many times in a second.
any suggestion.

Comment: Please add some code we can review and offer help with.

Comment: Plenty of code out there that throttle or debounce

Comment: yes debounce  works, could you  please add it as an answer? thanks

Comment: This problem has definitely been solved before.  As pseudo-pseudo code, start by setting a timer on each keyDown event.  Reset the timer on each new keyDown event if the timer doesn't end.  Once it ends, fire the update!  Simple!

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Way you can do this:

```
var debounceTimeout = null;

searchInput.on('change keyup', function(event){
  clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
  debounceTimeout = setTimeout(searchEvents, 500);
});
```

also you can handling this by a lot of ways like set a var with bool value, and when success let it false and back to true when search trigger ..etc

Answer (score 0):

I create a JSFiddle to show you an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmo61q89/

Credits go to David Walsh (https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Add this debounce function to your code:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

Then, add an event listener to your input:

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

var searchFunction = debounce(function() {
  console.log('seach code here')
}, 250);

input.addEventListener('keyup', searchFunction);
```